# How to get features in a certain radius around point from mapbox dataset?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I need to get features in a certain radius around specific point. Let's say i have an address and need to count all metro stations near this address.

Metro stations are uploaded to mapbox side as a dataset.

How can i list fetch and process these features using mapbox API?

---

Additional question:

Is there any possibility to get them from mapbox style (layer) attached to map after style is loaded. I can't find right event for fetching `renderedFeatures` (there is multiple edge cases, when user can zoomin and renderedFeatures will contain less points then fit in 1km radius)

Answer (score 0):

You can access your dataset using the Mapbox [Dataset API](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#the-dataset-object). This doesn't require Mapbox-GL-JS - it's a totally separate API, and the dataset doesn't need to be displayed anywhere.

You can then use the Turf library to filter points within a certain distance of the address, using the [`distance()`](http://turfjs.org/docs/#distance) function.

#### Update

The correct answer these days is to use the [tileQuery API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#tilequery), which takes a `radius` parameter.

Comment: Yep, but you know loading 40mb of dataset or even 3mb not sane thing. I remember in the past (if i not mixup things) mapbox API had radius parameter or something like that. I can't find anything like that in a current mapbox documentation. To load all dataset - doesn't work. There is need for some features list reducing.